# Boto - How to delete a record set from route53 -Tried to delete resource record set  but it was not found

Tags: python, boto, amazon-route53

I am using the following to delete route53 records.  I get no error messages.

```
conn = Route53Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
changes = ResourceRecordSets(conn, zone_id)
change = changes.add_change("DELETE",sub_domain, "A", 60,weight=weight,identifier=identifier)
change.add_value(ip_old)
changes.commit()
```

all required fields are present and they match..weight, identifier,
ttl=60 etc.\

e.g.

```
test.com. A 111.111.111.111 60 1 id1
test.com. A 111.111.111.222 60 1 id2
```

I want to delete 111.111.111.222 and the record set.

So, what is the proper way to delete a record set?

For a record set, I will have multiple values that are distinguished
by a unique identifier.  When an ip address becomes in active I want
to remove from route53.  I am using a a poor mans load balancing.

```
Here is the meta of the record  want to delete.  
{'alias_dns_name': None,
  'alias_hosted_zone_id': None,
  'identifier': u'15754-1',
  'name': u'hui.com.',
  'resource_records': [u'103.4.xxx.xxx'],
  'ttl': u'60',
  'type': u'A',
  'weight': u'1'}



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/classes/redis_ha.py", line 353, in <module>
    deleteRedisSubDomains(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key,platform=platform,sub_domain=sub_domain,redis_domain=redis_domain,zone_id=zone_id,ip_address=ip_address,weight=1,identifier=identifier)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/classes/redis_ha.py", line 341, in deleteRedisSubDomains
    changes.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/boto/route53/record.py", line 131, in commit
    return self.connection.change_rrsets(self.hosted_zone_id, self.to_xml())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/boto/route53/connection.py", line 291, in change_rrsets
    body)
boto.route53.exception.DNSServerError: DNSServerError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-05-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidChangeBatch</Code><Message>Tried to delete resource record set hui.com., type A, SetIdentifier 15754-1  but it was not found</Message></Error><RequestId>9972af89-cb69-11e1-803b-7bde5b9c457d</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need all of those parameters for add_change?

[Look at add_change here.](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.0/ref/route53.html)

Default parameters are given to the function, so you may be over-specifying by providing weight and TTL.

Try leaving weight and TTL out (you may need to keep identifier). [This blog](http://danieljamesscott.org/17-software/development/33-manipulating-aws-route53-entries-using-boto.html) provides a simple example of deleting records:

Also, I can't see the values of your parameters that you're passing, but ensure their integrity and try including a '.' at the end of your subdomain

Answer (score 1):

I tried similar example and had to specify all fields including weight and ttl for a successful deletion. (By keeping it default, it did not work).  Could not produce the original problem with weighted DNS record and explicitly passed ttl.

Answer (score 0):

## boto3

```
import boto3

client = boto3.connect('route53')
hosted_zone_id = "G5LEP7LWYS8WL2"

response = client.change_resource_record_sets(
    ChangeBatch={
        'Changes': [
            {
                'Action': 'DELETE',
                'ResourceRecordSet': {
                    'Name': 'test.example.com',
                    'ResourceRecords': [
                        {
                            'Value': '10.1.1.1',
                        },
                    ],
                    'Type': 'A',
                },
            },
        ]
    },
    HostedZoneId=hosted_zone_id,
)

print(response)
```

Source: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.change_resource_record_sets

## boto

```py
import boto
from boto.route53.record import ResourceRecordSets

conn = boto.connect_route53()

hosted_zone_id = "G5LEP7LWYS8WL2"
record_sets = ResourceRecordSets(conn, hosted_zone_id)

change = record_sets.add_change("DELETE", "test.example.com", "A")
change.add_value("10.1.1.1")

response = record_sets.commit()
print(response)
```

Source: https://danieljamesscott.org/17-software/development/33-manipulating-aws-route53-entries-using-boto.html